# How to choose optimum length for op-amp design?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

I've heard that minimum length is discouraged in analog design due to matching problem but what's the drawback of using very long transistors apart from the size and resistance?

Based on the following design, where should device length be small and large? I think lengths at the input need to be small because high resistance is required in stage 1, but what about the current mirror? What about cascodes?

[image: design]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, stop thinking of transistors in terms of resistance, think in terms of transconductance, understand it, use it.

First order effects:
- current density, regime of operation, range of operation.
Your W/L ratio and the bias current are the really the only things that you can change in a given topology.  The characteristics of the devices' in sub-threshold, Triode and active region are determined by current density and length.  Typically the MOSFETs in the diff pair will be active, short and high transconductance.  Your bias generator will be long and operational in the triode or subthreshold.

second order effects:
- Matching, noise etc.
General statements about matching should be avoided, it is process dependant.  For example pocket (Halo implanted) transistors are designed to match at Vth.  More Analog like transistors have different Vth vs. L relationships and also tend to be different.  As an example, one mechanism for mismatch is LER (Line edge roughness) of the gate, to control this you will need a wider gate, but to maintain the same W/L you then need a longer gate as well.  In this case a longer gate appears to match better, in reality it is because it is wider.  But is is one of many effects, and some times a longer gate DOES match better. Typically matching is accomplished through layout not just length.

In certain types of noise a larger gates is noisier and in others a smaller gate is noisier.  It is often better to run more current through, make a shorter device with more Gm and then filter out the out of band noise.

In short there is no one simple answer, and no substitution for learning.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not exactly something that can be addressed in a single answer, especially because you don't exactly tell what you care more: noise or current consumption? What about gain and GBW? And what about stability? Do you need it to be unity gain stable or not?

The biggest issue is noise, and the noisy guys are M1,2,3 and 4. That's because their noise is amplified while the other mosfet noise is not.

Flicker noise is proportional to \$(WL)^{-1}\$. You want to keep L high then. High L means also less offset, but again, is this an issue?

To lower thermal noise instead you need to keep low the overdrive voltage of the input differential pair, and to lower both noise contributes you want to rise the overdrive voltage of the mirror transistors, so maybe you'd like to play around with the simulator to lower L as it suits you.

Of course bigger L means slower transistors since the gate capacity rises, but maybe you are designing something that does not need to be fast...

You can also read this: [op amp design](http://www2.ing.unipi.it/~a008309/mat_stud/CMA/AA2013/Dispense/Chapter_3/Chap_3_2_opamp_design.pdf), in my opinion it's pretty clear and can help you in understanding what device length is about.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not asking for specifics. I'm just asking for a general idea from someone with experience designing op-amps.

Comment: Well I am not experienced but my professor (who wrote the pdf linked) is quite good at designing so you might want to go through it carefully. I hope linking is ok for the community, I might also copy his work in the answer giving him all the credits but it seems pointless to me.